# 1 domain name multiple external servers

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, apache2

I wanted to point multiple external server ip to one domain so when user wants ABC directory it will be served by server1 and when he will required directory XYZ it will be sserved by server 2

Not the subdomain scenario :)

Answer (score 5):

Get a reverse proxy that redirects as needed. It is not part of what DNS does. DNS resolves host names to IP addresses and doesn ot care about concepts like "folder".

Comment: I use cloudflare for dns it would be interesting to test how this scenario work with one main front server and multiple external subservers

Comment: By setting it up. This here is per site rules not a palce to teach you the basics of administration.

Comment: I appreciated your help but my comment wasnt a question :) so no point to be rude :)